# Find all complex roots of this equation.

Tags: complex-numbers

The equation is :

$$ \bar{z} + 1 = iz^2 + |z|^2 $$

I've tried substituting

$$ \bar{z} =x-iy  $$
$$ z = x  +iy $$

On simplification and comparison of real and imaginary parts, this yields two equations :

$$ y^2-x^2 = y $$
$$ x + 1 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy $$

Can anyone tell me how to solve these equations ?
Simpler Solutions would also be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: You can tell pretty much "by inspection" that $z=i$ is a root and, indeed, the system you derived has $x=0,y=1$ as a solution. This allows you to reduce the quartic equation you get in the end to a cubic, and check whether other roots exist.

Comment: Thanks. I guess there's nothing else one can do except intuitive guesswork ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $x^2=y^2-y$ in the second one to obtain $(1+2y)x=2y^2-y-1=(2y-1)(y-1)$. Therefore, no solution has $y=-\frac12$. Hence you obtain $$\begin{cases}x=\frac{2y^2-y-1}{1+2y}\\ \left(\frac{(2y-1)(y-1)}{1+2y}\right)^2=y^2-y\\ y\ne -\frac12\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}y=1\\ x=0\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}x=\frac{(2y-1)(y-1)}{1+2y}\\ (y-1)(2y-1)^2=(1+2y)^2y\\ y\ne-\frac12\end{cases}$$

the equation in $y$ alone is $$12y^2-4y+1=0$$ which has no real solutions. So, $z=i$.

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{vmatrix}
1&-1&-x^2&0\\
0&1&-1&-x^2\\
1&-2x&x^2-x-1&0\\
0&1&-2x&x^2-x-1
\end{vmatrix}=0$
The above equation is Sylvester's dialytic eliminant as applied to your system of equations. The elements of the determinant are terms, sans the ys, of the two equations that you developed. Solution of the eliminant equation
$3x-4x^3=0$
gives all values of x shared by your two equations. Substitution of each value into one of your two equations and solving will give the corresponding y.

So that you will be able to solve a similar system in future here is the eliminant for two quadratic equations in two unknowns:
$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0\\
gx^2+hxy+jy^2+kx+ly+m=0
\end{array}\right.$

$\begin{vmatrix}
c&bx+e&ax^2+dx+f&0\\
0&c&bx+e&ax^2+dx+f\\
j&hx+l&gx^2+kx+m&0\\
0&j&hx+l&gx^2+kx+m
\end{vmatrix}=0$

The system you had was one that  resolved into something simple, but in general you can expect a resolution into a quartic (degree 4) equation.

Answer (score 1):

from the first equation we obtain $$|x-y|=\sqrt{x+1}$$ if $$x\geq y$$ then we have $$y=x-\sqrt{x+1}$$ and if $$x<y$$ we get $$y=x+\sqrt{x+1}$$ and you can plug this in the seconde equation which is easy to solve

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried to do this by using Euler's formula, but didn't succeed. Are there any other methods to solve the original equation in z ?